# Compilr error: expected end of statement

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, return-value

I am a newbie in programming. I was doing practise on some VB code but i got that error mentioned on the subject.

Here are the codes

```
Function hypotenuse(ByVal a As Single, ByVal b As Single) As Single
Return Math.Sqrt((a ^ 2 ) + (b ^ 2))
End function
```

The error is highlighted at the return expression "Math".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB6/VBA, return value variable name of a function is the function name itself.

```
Function hypotenuse(ByVal a As Single, ByVal b As Single) As Single
    hypotenuse = Math.Sqr((a ^ 2) + (b ^ 2))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't know that I thought it accept both ways. And yes when I used function name it went like a charm. I appreciate for your help